# ошибка symfony 3.0.9 php7 twig cache:clear

Tags: symfony, twig, php7

ошибка symfony 3.0.9 php7 twig cache:clear
  [Twig_Error_Runtime]
  The "core" extension is not enabled.

Script Sensio\Bundle\DistributionBundle\Composer\ScriptHandler::clearCache handling the post-update-cmd event terminated with an exception

[RuntimeException]
  An error occurred when executing the "'cache:clear --no-warmup'" command:

```
[Twig_Error_Runtime]                                                     
The "core" extension is not enabled.
```

.
вот такая ошибка при composer update

Answer (score 0):

откат до версии php 5.6 
php5.6-mysql
php5.6-xml
php5.6-mbstring
удаление всех кешей  
удаление содержимого папки vendor 
удаление composer.lock

composer install 
мне помогло